# Is a redux-saga an efficient replacement for a middleware?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'm writing some exception logging code using the `raven-js` lib, and I'd like to log every `redux action` to create a breadcrumb trail of pre-exception activity.

I know this is a [use case for middleware](https://github.com/ngokevin/redux-raven-middleware), but I'd find it much easier/more flexible to write a simple saga:

```
function* logReduxAction(action) {
     // promisified Raven.captureBreadcrumb()
     yield logBreadcrumb({ 'redux',action.type })
}

export const exceptionSagas = [
   fork(takeEvery, '*', logReduxAction),

]
```

Is this an anti-pattern? Is capturing an action via saga notably less efficient than middleware? Or some other 'gotcha'?

Answer (score 0):

Well redux-saga `is` a middleware. What you are asking is should you use ready-made middleware for logging events or come up with your own solution using sagas. I would say doesn't matter that much, use a solution which better suits you.